# <!DOCTYPE html> breaks flexbox flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 2 boxes based around flexbox that will match each others height if text in one box is more than the other.

With `<!DOCTYPE html>` it doesn't stretch but without the tag it works as expected.

Question: Do I need this tag or can I remove it or is there a way around this?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif; color: #9E888A; 
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100em;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.fullcontainer {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  background:#ECF0F1;
  color:#808B8D;
}

.container {
  position:relative;
  max-width:1200px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:40px 0px 40px 0px;
}

.content {
  flex:1; 
  margin-right:310px;
}

.gridlg--fit > .grid-cell {
  flex: 1;
}
    
.gridlg--full > .grid-cell {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
    
.gridlg--1of2 > .grid-cell {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
    
.gridlg--1of3 > .grid-cell {
  flex: 0 0 33.3333%;
}
    
.gridlg--1of4 > .grid-cell {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}
    
.gridlg--1of5 > .grid-cell {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
}
    
.row1 {
  flex:1;
  background:#ccc;
}
    
.row2 {
  background:#000;
  width:100%;
  height:30px;
}
    
.grid--flexCells > .grid-cell {
  display: flex;
}
    
.grid--gutters > .grid-cell {
  padding: 5px;
}
    
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
    
.grid-cell {
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Mobile First Responsive Navigation</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">    
      <div class="fullcontainer">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="content"> 
            <div class="grid grid--flexcells grid--gutters grid--full gridsm--full gridmd--full gridlg--1of2">
              <div class="grid-cell">
                <div class="row1">
                   test<br />
                   test<br />
                   test<br />
                   test<br />
                   test<br />
                </div>      
                <div class="row2">
                   test
                </div>               
              </div>
              <div class="grid-cell">
                <div class="row1">
                   test
                </div>      
                <div class="row2">
                   test
                </div>          
              </div>
           </div>
          </div>         
        </div>
      </div>   
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, you need to declare Doctype. There is something else in your HTML not validating properly. For starters you're missing <head>

Comment: I've added the head section but 100% sure it's the doctype causing this as I've stripped everything out and it works without the doctype and doesn't work with it.

Comment: @StuFu - HTML5 spec explicitly states the <head> tag is optional http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/syntax.html#optional-tags

Comment: Just clarifying you didn't actually just shove your CSS under all your HTML correct? You put it in an actual style sheet or defined the styles at the top?

Comment: my css is in styles.ccs as shown in the `<head>` just under my html for convenience here

Comment: I can't understand what's causing this, I have 2 seperate documents pointing to the same css file and 1 will display correctly and 1 won't. I have compared these with notepad++ comapre and they're exactly the same..

Comment: Did you have a BOM at the top of the file and did you accidentally include the `<!DOCTYPE html>` before the BOM?

Comment: @dave Can't believe I never knew this. Looks like it might have some issues in IE but no questioning that you're correct. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @tomharrison I confirmed the answer from Rutvik is correct and works - it's really odd the Doctype removal would do what it does, but you definitely want to keep it in.

Comment: yeah had a BOM and it worked with this and when i managed to remove this it broke again

Comment: @tomharrison Reading your comments I'm a bit confused as to what you are after as Rutvik's answer seems to be the correct solution. The two `.grid-cell` containers are stretching to the height of their container (https://jsfiddle.net/hnuq1vyv/). The contents of `.grid-cell` will not stretch because they are `div`s and are therefore `display: block;` by default. Could you clarify why Rutvik's solution is not viable?

Answer (score 1):

Add in Css

.grid-cell{display:flex}

Comment: yeah that flex's the grid-cell so they all stretch to the same height, however the content dislayed within the grid-cell doesn't stretch to match the height of grid-cell. I've given up and just going to use min-height although I would love to find a solution to this. Seems to be the way the browser handles the file, in quirks mode it works and when in standards mode it doesn't